# How can I avoid passing too many input parameters in AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, object, android-asynctask

I have an `AsyncTask` where I need to pass multiple parameters to my constructor. I know its bad practice to pass too many parameters and its better to break the method into smaller chunks to avoid this situation but I'm not allowed to break the method so my only way is to find an alternative to pass parameters in a better way. In my `AsyncTask`, I have created a constructor.

Is it possible to create a model class with value object and pass them? Do I need getters and setters for this?

```
 class UpdateAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private String productId;
        int mutationAmount;
        boolean isOpeningStock;
        FlightLegIdentifier fli;
        String crew;
        String tabletId;

        UpdateAsyncTask(final String productId, final int mutationAmount, final boolean isOpeningStock,
                         final String flightKey,
                         final FlightLegIdentifier fli,
                         final String crew,
                         final String tabletId,
                         final AirFiApplication airFiApplication) {

            this.productId = productId;
            this.mutationAmount = mutationAmount;
            this.isOpeningStock = isOpeningStock;
            this.fli = fli;
            this.tabletId = tabletId;
            this.crew = crew;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            productStockAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            StockUtils.saveMutation(productId, mutationAmount, isOpeningStock, flightKey, fli, crew,
            tabletId, getAirFiApplication());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can create a pojo instead and pass it to Aysnctask

Comment: You can create a model class, then pass that model into UpdateAsyncTask  constructor. Also create setters and getters into your model

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html

Comment: If the problem is the length of parameter in this constructor, well even using a specific class, you will just move the problem to this class.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the amount of parameters you have now. Leave it like it is and spend your time somewhere else.

Comment: @greenapps The problem occurs when you try to use the constructor: you need a parameter list with 8 parameters, and there's nothing to indicate what parameter means what.  Some languages, like C#, Swift, and Ada, allow you to include the parameter names in the parameter list when calling, so large numbers of parameters are, I believe, less of a problem in those languages.  This is my number #1 missing feature that I wish Java had.

Comment: `there's nothing to indicate what parameter means what.` ??? The parameter name shkuld be enough.

Answer (score 3):

you can create a model class and pass it as parameter to `AsyncTask`

here is an example:

```
 private static class ModelClass {
    int length;
    int height;

    ModelClass(int l, int h) {
        this.length = l;
        this.height = h;
    }
}
```

Define the `AsyncTask` task

```
 private class MyTask extends AsyncTask <ModelClass, Void, Void> {


    @Override
     protected void onPreExecute(){

        }

    @Override
    protected void doInBackground(ModelClass... params) {
        int length = params[0].length;
        int height = params[0].height;
        ...
        //here u can perform your saveMutation() function using the parameters...
    }

    @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
}
```

use the `Aysnctask`

```
 //Initialize model class
ModelClass params = new ModelClass(10,10);

//pass it to asynch tash
MyTask myTask = new MyTask();
myTask.execute(params);
```

Comment: You should use a more standard notation for your class, `Model_class` should be `ModelClass`

Comment: when you are getting values for the StockUtils..class initialize the object using those values and then start the asynctask ...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class defining the parameters to be passed to the AsyncTask.

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@AllArgsConstructor(suppressConstructorProperties=true)
@Getter
@Setter
class Product {
  private String productId; 
  private int mutationAmount; 
  private boolean isOpeningStock;
  private String flightKey;
  private FlightLegIdentifier fli;
  private String crew;
  private String tabletId;
  private AirFiApplication airFiApplication;
} 

class UpdateAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Product, Void, Void> {
  ...
  ...
  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Product... params) {
  }
}
```

I'm using Project Lombok for the annotations (https://projectlombok.org/).
You have to add the following to your `build.gradle`.

`dependencies {
  ...
  compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.12.6'
}`

**Note:** You can do the same for the returned value from the `AsyncTask` as well.

Thanks

Comment: Do I need to a constructor for this? (Similar to my async task?) @Sri

Comment: Hi Baabidi, Yes. I user lombok library for the constructor,getter, setter, equals etc., purpose (https://projectlombok.org/). Add the following to your dependencies.

Comment: @AxelH, you dont have to code when you have project lombok. (It cuts down the verbose part of your code with one word annotations). You can read more here - https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/why-the-lazy-coder-in-you-would-enjoy-project-lombok/

Comment: @AxelH Lombok is a standard library used across java professional world (spring boot) & the verbosity that getters, setters create for classes with even 10 fields is known well. Just go and search for lombok in github and you'll see the usage (https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=org.projectlombok%3Alombok&type=Code&ref=searchresults)

Comment: You are still out of the subject ... why does OP need this "magic project" in this situation ? This will not reduce the number of parameter in the constructor ... so this is useless.

Comment: Alright. Last comment. (1) The Question was avoiding input params in AsyncTask and not really the constructor. If the requestparams object sent to the AsyncTask needs as many, one needs to have a constructor with as many. (2) Lombok is not forced. Its an option and over a long time i have found it to be extremely effective in avoiding boilerplate functions like getters and setters. Ciao !